# python regex doesn't match '+' in phone number

Tags: python, regex

I have regex to match Australian phone numbers

```py
import re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r"\b((\+61|0061|0)?\s?)?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\b")

lists = phoneRegex.finditer(
    " +61745856965, 0061456123789, 0478563214, 0412 452 789, 61 789963258")

for list in lists:
    print(list.group())
```

Output is

```
0061456123789
0478563214
0412 452 789
 789963258
```

What do I need to match first number `+61745856965` ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is the word boundary `\b` here. If you remove it, the `+` is properly captured. This does cause some problems with spaces being captured though.

Comment: ...specifically, the \b finds the first word boundary which is between the "+" and the "6", rendering the following plus sign a non-match

Comment: Thanks @Kraigolas  I updated regex to `\s?((\+61|0061|0)?\s?)?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\b` and it works.  But would you tell me why `\b` fails even if I add a space before number?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMaurer , I used https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb((%5C%2B61%7C0061%7C0)%3F%5Cs%3F)%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cs%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cs%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cb   and didn't see `WordBoundry `  between `+` and `61` so I assumed I am doing something wrong

Comment: Try replacing your first \b with a positive lookbehind (?<=[^0-9\+]).

Comment: ...or better yet a negative lookbehind on the negation of that is better;. (?<!([0-9\+]).   That has the added benefit of working at start of string.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMaurer . I had completely forgotten about those. Reading https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html   now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial `\b` is causing the problem, because `+` is not a word character, so `\b\+` is never going to match `+61` except when preceded by a word char (which it won't be).

Use this:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r"((\+61|\b0061|\b0)?\s?)?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\b")
```

The change here is to apply the `\b` only to the non `"+61"` prefix.

---

If you want to match the last example `61 789963258` *including* the leading `61`, add `"\b61 "` to the list of prefixes:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r"((\+61|\b0061|\b61 |\b0)?\s?)?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\b")
```